# Как организовать поиск вложенных файлов, не являющихся директориями с помощью очереди

Tags: java, файлы

Реализовать логику метода `getFileTree`, который должен в директории root найти список всех файлов, включая вложенные.

Необходимо использовать очередь, без рекурсии.

```
File directory = new File("название директории");
    for(File file : directory.listFiles())
    {
        if(file.isDirectory())
        {

        }
        else {


        }
    }
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, слово "очередь" стоит понимать как коллекцию Queue 
или это какой-то особый способ представления задачи?

Comment: Какой ваш родной язык?

Answer (score 3):

```
Queue<File> que = new LinkedList<>();
que.add(new File("название директории"));
while (que.peek() != null) {
    File directory = que.remove();
    for(File file : directory.listFiles())
    {
        if(file.isDirectory())
           que.add(file);
        else {


        }
    }
}
```